# How to make a varlist loop with multiple variables imported from csv

Tags: python, loops, csv, variables, import

I want a varlist that contain two vars. The vars are the second and the third column of my csv file.
I'm able to create the varlist with the orderdate column. But the "purchasestatus" value is not the value from the same line as "orderdate" in my code below.

```
import bsScraper
import test
import requests
import csv
import sys
import time

with open('input/price.csv', 'r') as file:
    next(file) # drop header
    orderdate = [row[1] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")]
    purchasestatus = [row[2] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")]

<THE LOOP IM MISSING>
# initialise scraper with time interval
# Example: scraper = bsScraper("5", "10-10-2022", "11-10-2022" )
scraper = bsScraper("purchasestatus", "orderdate", "orderdate" )

# get raw data as list of list
headers, data = scraper.get_data()

# get data in a json format
json_data = scraper.get_data("json")

# print output
print(json_data)
```

How do I correctly add the "purchasestatus" column to the varlist in where both values of "purchasestatus" and "orderdate" are from the same line?

EDIT:
I updated the code above.

I have a csv file and every row is an order. I want to scrape the article price (json_data output) at a certain date for every single order.

input.csv

```
paid,purchasestatus,orderdate
1,5,10-10-2022
1,8,11-10-2022
0,0,11-10-2022
```

For the first row `scraper variable should look like

```
scraper = bsScraper("5", "10-10-2022", "10-10-2022" )
```

For the second row `scraper` variable should look like

```
scraper = bsScraper("5", "11-10-2022", "11-10-2022" )
```

For every order(row) I want the price printed. I want to do this with a loop. Normally I have 1 variable which is read from the `csv` and I use

```
varlist = [row[1] for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")]
for var in varlist:
```

But I don't know how to do this with with 2 variables read from the csv. How to loop this? I hope I'm clear enough now.

Comment: You can set the file pointer (method `seek`) back to beginning or after the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second list comprehension doesn't work because there's nothing left in the file to read. You need to do `file.seek(0)` and `next(file)` to go back to the beginning of the file.

But it's better not to use two loops. Loop over the file once, appending to each list in the loop.

```
orderdate = []
purchasestatus = []
with open('input/price.csv', 'r') as file:
    next(file) # drop header
    for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=','):
        orderdate.append(row[1])
        purchasestatus.append(row[2])
```

That said, do you really need two lists? It's usually better to keep related data together in tuples or dictionaries, rather than in parallel lists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now its printing the complete input for each column. I need to print row per row, line per line as I asked. Like "for var in varlist:" Could you add that to your answers please and I'll approve your answer

Comment: What is `varlist`?

Comment: `test("purchasestatus", "orderdate", "orderdate" )` isn't using the variables, those are string literals.

Comment: I updated my question. I tried my best

Comment: I'm not familiar with `bsScraper`. I tried googling but couldn't find it.

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for is `for date,  status in zip(orderdate, purchasestatus):`

Comment: Its customized CmcScraper. ---------------- Yes I added exactly what you said and its gives me this error ---------------- for coin in orderdate
                         ^
SyntaxError: expected ':'

Comment: Like it says, you forgot the `:` at the end: `for coin in orderdate:`.

Comment: That was not the issue. But I solved it all with your help